# How can I create two <div>, but one of them has to be fixed in the center

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, styled-components

css is not my strong point. I am trying to create two Boxes or two divs, but one of them has to be fixed in the center of the page, and the other one has to adapt, being just next to the first one. It is just to build a textField in the middle of the page (the first div), and a loading spinner (as the second div) next to the textField.

I am trying something like this using `styled-components`:

```js
<StyledBox>
   <StyledTextFieldContainer>
     <TextField/>
   </StyledTextFieldContainer>
   <StyledLoaderContainer>
     Loading...
   </StyledLoaderContainer>
</StyledBox>

const StyledBox = styled(Box)`
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
`;

const StyledTextFieldContainer = styled(Box)`
  width: 70%
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
`;

const StyledLoaderContainer = styled(Box)`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

The problem with this is that my `textField` is not in the exactly in the center because the `Loader` is pushing it a bit to the left (I suppose this is because both of them are in the center.

CodeSandBox with the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-tree-r4tdm?file=/src/App.js

How could I place the `textField` fixed in the center of the page, and the Loader just next to it?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], like codesandbox

Comment: Sorry, I just added the sandBox example, thank You!

Comment: Imo this is more of a material-ui question so I've updated the tags to get attention of material-ui folks...

Comment: grid would be easier to set i guess https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-germain-gvlit

Comment: Yep, that worked well @G-Cyrillus thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hey You want it like this? then just add one line there in code margin-top or padding-top, according to your requirement.

```
const StyledBox = styled(Box)`
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  //align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40vh;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on the sandbox, this code should do you fine if you only want the div(s) to be centered on the page.

```
import { Box, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledBox>
      <div width="70%">
        <TextField label="Fixed in the center" />
      </div>
      <div>
        Loading...
      </div>
    </StyledBox>
  );
}

const StyledBox = styled(Box)`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background:red;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
`;
```

Comment: I can't use the `position: absolute` property because I am rendering stuff below. I would have to move everything I have below the searchBox according to that new position which seems a bit odd.

Comment: And I do not want both divs in the center, just the first one. I don't care about the second div's position as long as it is next to the first div.